# Removing mulitple selected Rows + with rowspan

Tags: javascript

I would like to delete selected rows with rowspan and an extra one below, a total of 4 rows, you can see that each 4 stack of rows represent 1 entry. The function deleteSelectedRows() below does not work correctly; it only deletes the one selected. Could you please help!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table  id="my_table" id="my_table" align="center" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >No</th>
        <th >Location</th>
        <th >Time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr> <!-- new entry #1 -->
        <td rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox">1a<td>
        <td>1a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2a</td>
        <td>2a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3a</td>
        <td>3a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td colSpan="3">4a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> <!-- new entry #2-->
        <td rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox">1b<td>
        <td>1b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2b</td>
        <td>2b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3b</td>
        <td>3b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td colSpan="3">4b</td>
      </tr>
     </thead></tbody>
    </table>
    <div><input type="button" value="Delete selected rows" onClick="deleteSelectedRows()"/></div>
</body>
</HTML>
   <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function deleteSelectedRows() {    
     var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
     var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table          
     for(var i=0; i< rowCount; i++) { //loops for all row in table 

      var row = table.rows[i]; //return a particular row              
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; //get check box onject               
      if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) { //wheather check box is selected                   
       table.deleteRow(i); //delete the selected row   

       rowCount = rowCount-1; //decrease rowcount by 1                   
       i--;               
      }             
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the possibility that multiple boxes could be checked with my first answer. Updated for my own satisfaction, I see that you've already accepted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you delete one row but because of your `rowspan=3` your row is represented by 3 rows. So you must delete as many as row as your rowspan value (+1 for the fourth). Like this :

```
function deleteSelectedRows() {    
 var table = document.getElementById('my_table');
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;        
 for(var i=0; i< rowCount; i++) {

  var row = table.rows[i];            
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];             
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   nbRows = row.cells[0].rowSpan + 1; // the number of row to delete
   for(var j=0; j<nbRows; j++) {       
    table.deleteRow(i); //delete the selected rows  
    rowCount--; 
   }
   i--;               
  }             
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML provided has some minor validation errors which I have corrected below. These were that the `<thead>` does not to encompass your entire table and should definitely not exist *after* the `<tbody>`. Also there is a duplicate `id` on the `<table>`. Please see the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) for valid table element order.

The problem you had is that the code ever only deleted one row which matched with a checked box. The `rowCount` would then decrease by 1 (from 9 to 8) but the logic to delete a row still depends on a checked box being found, but this would never be true again since you just deleted that row!

<strike>The updated JavaScript first finds the rowIndex, as you already had, but now breaks out and then uses this index as a starting position to iterate backwards deleting 4 rows.</strike>

**Edit:** The updated JavaScript works backwards, avoiding all the incrementing and decrementing and now works when multiple inputs are checked. Sorry I missed the possibility that multiple boxes could be checked with my first answer!

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrAT5/3/) or code below.

**HTML** (now valid)

```
<table  id="my_table" align="center" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <!-- new entry #1 -->
      <td rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox"/>1a</td>
      <td>1a</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2a</td>
      <td>2a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3a</td>
      <td>3a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="3">4a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- new entry #2-->
      <td rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox"/>1b</td>
      <td>1b</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3b</td>
      <td>3b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="3">4b</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div><input type="button" value="Delete selected rows" onClick="deleteSelectedRows()"/></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function deleteSelectedRows() {    
  var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table

  for (var rowIndex = table.rows.length - 1; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--) { //loops for all row in table 
    var row = table.rows[rowIndex]; //return a particular row              
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; //get check box object               

    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) { //wheather check box is selected
      // rowIndex = row with checkbox on
      for (var i = rowIndex + 3; i >= rowIndex; i--) {
        table.deleteRow(i); //delete the selected row  
      }
    }
  }
}
```